# Why use session_set_cookie_params instead of set_cookie?

Tags: php

These two functions are pretty similar. Why would someone choose to use one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session_set_cookie_params is a function to change (set) the parameters of the session cookie, the cookies send to be used for the session. Set_cookie_params is the function that sets parameters for all the cookies you create, which can also be used without using sessions.

Hope that clarifies it for you.